How to redirect only the powershell output without errors to a file
Need help in a powershell script . My code
foreach($line in Get-Content C:\Users\G661600\Downloads\sublist.txt) { 
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("$line") | select IPAddressToString }

This gives me the IP addresses of domains contained in sublist.txt. Sublist.txt also contains some domains which donot resolve to any IP. If I redirect this output to a file it also contains the errors (for the domains which don't resolve)
My query is

How to get get the domain names against the IP addresses
How to get only the output omitting the errors from the output file


You need to add Where-Object

Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share how do you redirect this output to a file…

This work by me:
$Adresses=("www.google.com","www.bing.com","domain.without.ip")

$Adresslist = @{}

foreach($line in $Adresses) { 
    $result = try {[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("$line")}
    catch {}
    $index = 0
    Foreach ($IP in ($result| select IPAddressToString)){
        
        $Null= $Adresslist.Add("[$index]$line", $IP.IPAddressToString)
        $index++

    }

}

$Adresslist

